# Get element using querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript, html, selectors-api

I have the html tag as,

```
<div data-id='test'></div>
```

I need to get this element using

```
document.querySelectorAll('[data-id="test"]');
```

But the above code returns always empty array. Please help me in getting the element using querySelectorAll().

Comment: Are you sure your JavaScript code is running **after** the DOM has loaded?

Comment: It doesn't return an empty array for me.  What @Pointy said

Comment: @Pointy Yes the DOM gets loaded before my JS execution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There shouldn't be any double quotes with your ID

```
document.querySelectorAll('[data-id=test]');
```

OR

```
document.querySelectorAll('div[data-id=test]');
```

And make sure you place this inside `onload` or make the JavaScript tag as `defer="defer"`